# Validating Form Fields on button click in office fabric Ui control

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, office-fabric

I have one TextField and PrimaryButton in my form.

On button click i want to validate textfield.If there is no value then fire requiredfield validation on button click and display message same as display on onGetErrorMessage event.

I know validation is fire onBlur event but i want to fire validation on button click.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to use `refs` to your `TextField`

```
<TextField ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} label='test' />
```

Now you can set `onGetErrorMessage` on click using `refs`

```
onClick(e){
    if(this.refs.input.value == undefined ||  this.refs.input.value == null || this.refs.input.value == '')
        this.refs.input.onGetErrorMessage = "you error message"
}
```

**Update 1:**  Check out this code [snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/rRlB5Mk04)

```
class FormExample extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state={
      inputError:''
    }
    this.ValidateText = this.ValidateText.bind(this)
  }
  ValidateText(e){
    this.setState({
      inputError:this.input.value?'':'testing'
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <TextField
            ref={(input) => { this.input = input; }}
            label="Name"
            errorMessage={this.state.inputError}
        />
          <input type='button' value='Submit'
          onClick={this.ValidateText} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is this.textInput? i am getting error on that. I am not able to found this.textInput and also not found this.refs.input.onGetErrorMessage ?

Comment: ya i am also getting the error.. i am creating snippet please wait for some time..

Comment: @PiyushDhamecha you are using *ref callback not string ref*, so to access the text field value use this: `this.textInput.value` :)

Comment: still i not able to found this.textInput. i am getting error "Property 'textInput' does not exist on type 'FabricControl'"

Comment: What if there are multiple textfields? Is it possible to show error message and red border on each empty textfield? Please let me know.